# So I deleted the Settings link. How to restore it?

Tags: windows-8.1

There's this link in startup menu folder(`C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`) that opens the *PC Settings* window(the one with the new UI), and I deleted it.

So now if I press `win + i` and click on *Change PC Settings*, nothing happens.

Is it possible to restore that link?

(I don't have access to another Windows 8.1 machine, only Windows 10, which doesn't have that window AFAIK)

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a shortcut to `explorer ms-settings:`, the app's URI. You can add e.g. `colors` to the URI to reach the Colors page in the app, like so: `explorer ms-settings:colors`.

You can borrow the icon for the shortcut from "C:\Windows\ImmersiveControlPanel\SystemSettings.exe" which is the executable this command runs.

It should also exist in Windows 10, though.

Comment: when I execute `explorer ms-settings:colors`, I get "no apps are installed to open this type of link(ms-settings)"

Comment: @Hrisip do any other Metro apps open? Does the SystemSettings.exe file exist? What happens if you press Win+I (for Immersive Control Panel)?

Comment: it does exist. It shows as expected. In question I've mentioned `win + i` already. So not sure what you're asking